# Jupyter kernel error after installing xbpch

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm a new user of python and jupyter notebook. Recently I installed xbpch(https://xbpch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package in anaconda prompt using: conda install -c conda-forge xbpch
And after that every time I open jupyter notebook, there is a kernel error with this traceback message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\snowflakes\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just a wild speculation: conda-forge is currently migrating packages to a new compiler infrastructure, but xbpch is not yet migrated. Maybe installing xbpch forced conda do pull in now incompatible packages. I would try reinstalling jupyter and jupyter-notebook and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you Jupyter directory (ex.`C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3`)
Then make a copy of `kernel.json` (e.x `kernel_old.json`) then open with notepad or you JS IDE.
Shoud be like this : 
`{
"argv": [
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python37\python.exe",
"-m",
"ipykernel_launcher",
"-f",
"{connection_file}"
],
"display_name": "Python 3",
"language": "python"
}`
Change the path with you Anaconda3 python in you case: `C:\Users\Anaconda3\python.exe`
Then start jupyter again.